# org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping, bag

Following is my code Here I am using multiple lists to fetch data from database.
On fetching data from hql query it is showing exception.

Pojo Class

```
public class BillDetails implements java.io.Serializable {

private Long billNo;
// other fields
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
private List<BillPaidDetails> billPaidDetailses = new ArrayList<BillPaidDetails>();
private Set productReplacements = new HashSet(0);
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
private List<BillProduct> billProductList = new ArrayList<BillProduct>();
//getter and setter
}
```

hmb.xml file

```
<class name="iland.hbm.BillDetails" table="bill_details" catalog="retail_shop">
        <id name="billNo" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="bill_no" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
 <bag name="billProductList" table="bill_product" inverse="true" lazy="false" fetch="join">
            <key>
                <column name="bill_no" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="iland.hbm.BillProduct" />
        </bag>
        <bag name="billPaidDetailses" table="bill_paid_details" inverse="true" lazy="false" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="bill_no" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="iland.hbm.BillPaidDetails" />
        </bag>
        <set name="productReplacements" table="product_replacement" inverse="true" lazy="false" fetch="join">
            <key>
                <column name="bill_no" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="iland.hbm.ProductReplacement" />
        </set>
    </class>
```

Hql query

```
String hql = "select distinct bd,sum(bpds.amount) from BillDetails as bd "
                    + "left join fetch bd.customerDetails as cd "
                    + "left join fetch bd.billProductList as bpd "
                    + "left join fetch bpd.product as pd "
                    +"left join fetch bd.billPaidDetailses as bpds "
                    + "where bd.billNo=:id "
                    + "and bd.client.id=:cid ";
```

I am trying following query to fetch data from database but this is showing 
`org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags`
How to resolve this

Comment: Have you tried changing your Lists to Sets?

Comment: This article may help you: http://blog.eyallupu.com/2010/06/hibernate-exception-simultaneously.html

Comment: What is the name of the unique id property on BillProduct?

Comment: Insted of List Sets are working. But I want to do with list

Comment: Do you really need to use lists?

Comment: If possible  with list then I want to use it.

Comment: Choosen simple way Converted all list to set

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Hibernate doesn't allow fetching more than one bag because that would generate a [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product).

Now, you will find lots of answers, blog posts, videos, or other resources telling you to use a `Set` instead of a `List` for your collections.

**That's terrible advice!**

Using `Sets` instead of `Lists` will make the `MultipleBagFetchException` go away, but the Cartesian Product will still be there.

### The right fix

Instead of using multiple `JOIN FETCH` in a single JPQL or Criteria API query:

```
List<Post> posts = entityManager.createQuery("""
    select p
    from Post p
    left join fetch p.comments
    left join fetch p.tags
    where p.id between :minId and :maxId
    """, Post.class)
.setParameter("minId", 1L)
.setParameter("maxId", 50L)
.getResultList();
```

You can do the following trick:

```
List<Post> posts = entityManager.createQuery("""
    select distinct p
    from Post p
    left join fetch p.comments
    where p.id between :minId and :maxId
    """, Post.class)
.setParameter("minId", 1L)
.setParameter("maxId", 50L)
.setHint(QueryHints.PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH, false)
.getResultList();

posts = entityManager.createQuery("""
    select distinct p
    from Post p
    left join fetch p.tags t
    where p in :posts
    """, Post.class)
.setParameter("posts", posts)
.setHint(QueryHints.PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH, false)
.getResultList();
```

As long as you fetch at most one collection using `JOIN FETCH`, you will be fine. By using multiple queries, you will avoid the Cartesian Product since any other collection but the first one is fetched using a secondary query.

Comment: I think this article is more relevant to actual loading of `Set`s http://blog.eyallupu.com/2010/06/hibernate-exception-simultaneously.html Also, changing bags to sets does not make join-fetch query result any less of a cartesian product, which by itself may be an issue with large collections.

Comment: at most one can be equated to not more than one. That means only one since it is not possible to query 0.5 table. my question is why the wording  "at most one" is used here

Comment: Vlad, what's the solution when we use @EntityGraph in JpaRepository?

Comment: Switch from that to a custom JpaRepository method that does what I  told you in this answer. That's the solution.

Answer (score 28):

For me I had the same error and I solved by adding the annotation of hibernate 
**@Fetch**

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="parent", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
private List<Child> childs;
```

Comment: What should I do if I want use fetch type Lazy

Answer (score 2):

<s>You can only join-fetch following one relation for an entity (either `billPaidDetailses` or `billProductList`).</s>

Consider using lazy associations and loading collections when they are needed, OR using lazy associations and loading collections manually with `Hibernate.initialize(..)`. At least that was the conclusion I came to when I had a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23676286/2780779).

<s>Either way it will take more than one query to the database.</s>

Comment: I don't agree. There are several ways to accomplish this without multiple queries, as other folk have answered, and allowing for multiple queries generates serious performance issues in many cases.

Comment: @IgorDonin you are right, it is possible. But it is not a silver bullet performance-wise. Imagine I have to load a container with, let's say 4 sets of 100 of elements each. Not so many, right? Join-fetch result query will be 100000000

Comment: Sure, you're right. I've seen cases in which over 750000 records were generated to populated 600 objects. Still possible ;)

Answer (score 2):

Changing to `Set` is the best solution. However, if you cannot not replace the `List` with `Set` (like in my case, there was a heavy use of JSF tags specific to `Lists`), and if you can use Hibernate proprietary annotations, you can specify `@IndexColumn (name = "INDEX_COL")`. That solution worked better for me, changing to `Set` would require tons of refactoring.

So, your code would be something like this:

```
@IndexColumn (name = "INDEX_COL")
private List<BillPaidDetails> billPaidDetailses = new ArrayList<BillPaidDetails>();

@IndexColumn (name = "INDEX_COL")
private List<BillProduct> billProductList = new ArrayList<BillProduct>();
```

As Igor suggested in the comments, you could also create proxy methods to return the lists. I haven't tried that, but would be a good alternative if you cannot use Hibernate proprietary annotations.

Comment: Not necessarily. You could add additional methods for the sets and proxy them to the lists.

Answer (score 1):

I find using `@PostLoad` annotated method in the entity most useful, I'd do something like

```
@PostLoad
public void loadCollections(){
     int s1 = productReplacements.size();
     int s2 = billProductList.size();
}
```

this way I'm able to fine control the eager loading and initialization of collections in the same transaction that loaded the entity.

Answer (score 0):

I used the new annotation @OrderColumn instead of @IndexColumn (deprecated see: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/IndexColumn.html) and it works now.

Annotate one of the collections with @OrderColumn
e.g.

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@OrderColumn
private List<AddressEntity> addresses = Lists.newArrayList();

@Builder.Default
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<BankAccountEntity> bankAccounts = Lists.newArrayList();
```

Answer (score -3):

Your request fetch too many data and HIbernate cannot load them all.
Reduce your request and/or configure your entities to retrieve just needed data