# Hibernate: Why load two bags would generate a cartesian product?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

When one tries to eagerly load two bags the following exception is thrown

> org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously
>   fetch  multiple bags

Acording to the following posts:

[org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24675340/org-hibernate-loader-multiplebagfetchexception-cannot-simultaneously-fetch-mult)

[Hibernate cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334970/hibernate-cannot-simultaneously-fetch-multiple-bags)

> Hibernate doesn't allow fetching more than one bag because that would generate a Cartesian product.

And both posts recommend the use of Sets instead of non-indexed Lists (bags).

My question is:

Why try to load two bags would generate a Cartesian product and using sets would not?

Answer (score 0):

A Cartesian product is generated in both cases — for bags and for sets. It doesn't matter what is used.

Meaning of this statement:

> Hibernate doesn't allow fetching more than one bag because that would generate a Cartesian product.

Hibernate can process a result of a Cartesian product using sets and can't using bags. You can refer for an example here:
[Hibernate Exception - Simultaneously Fetch Multiple Bags](http://blog.eyallupu.com/2010/06/hibernate-exception-simultaneously.html)