# MultipleBagFetchException not happening in Hibernate 4, does in 5

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee

I'm migrating my WildFly version from 8.1 (Hibernate 4.3.5) to 11.0 (Hibernate 5.1.10), and a new error just appears now:

Caused by: org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags: [InformeMensalINR.aplicacoesEfetuadas, InformeMensalINR.recursosTransferidos]

The mapping is below and used to work fine on Hibernate 4:

`@OneToMany(mappedBy="informeMensalINR",cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER,orphanRemoval=true)
public List<RecursoTransferido> getRecursosTransferidos() {
    return recursosTransferidos;
}`

`@OneToMany(mappedBy="informeMensalINR",cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER,orphanRemoval=true)
public List<AplicacaoEfetuada> getAplicacoesEfetuadas() {
    return aplicacoesEfetuadas;
}`

Any ideas on why is this happening now? In WildFly 8 it works great. I didn't find anything in Hibernate JIRA related to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised why this worked in WildFly 8! Because Hibernate was never able to load two Lists eagerly because this produces a cartesian product.

Please find a detailed explanation here:

[org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24675340/org-hibernate-loader-multiplebagfetchexception-cannot-simultaneously-fetch-mult/24676806)

Comment: I think I realized what just happened. This piece of code is deployed on WildFly but is not called (it's used in a standalone app). In WFLY 8, probably this exception would be thrown only in runtime. WFLY 11 seems to check it in deployment time.